# Syntax error in RAILS - unexpected ','

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add the user's initials as an avatar to the navbar through a partial _avatar, but I'm getting a Syntax error for some reason.

**/shared/_navbar**

```
<%= show_avatar(@user), class: "img-circle avatar-small" %>
```

It says: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...er.append=( show_avatar(@user), class: "img-circle avatar-sm... ... ^

**users/_avatar**

```
<div class=“avatar-circle”>
    <span class="initials">
        <%= @user.lastname[0..1].upcase %>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any ideas why? 
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the comma before ‘class:’.

Comment: I tried, but it's still gives me an error.. maybe I need to structure the class somehow differently for show tag?

Comment: Where is the show_avatar method?

Comment: It is in UsersHelper def show_avatar(user)
        render partial: 'users/avatar'
    end

Comment: It is working all fine, until I tried adding classes to the tag itself... It works with div classes for some reason.. But I need this to bee within the tag as the avatar is used as a link to the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I was duplicating the effort. I just left the div class in the partial _avatar. worked!